# Cucumber data driven

Tags: cucumber

What is the best way to fill in a web form with more than 20 number of fields?
Can I use combination of data table and scenario outline to avoid writing steps for each and every field in the form?

I wrote the feature something like this.. But dont know how to implement step definition for this ? 
Somebody please help..

```
        Scenario Outline: Test successful registration of a new user
        Then I enter email address of new user as "<customerEmail>"
        And I click on CreateAccount button
       Then I enter my personal informations

      | Title | CustomerFirstName | CustomerLastName | Email | Password | DOB |
      | <title> | <cFname> | <cLname> | <email> | <pwd> | <dob> |

        And I enter my address informations
       | FirstName | LastName | Company | Address | AddressLine2 | City | State 
       | ZipCode | Country |
       | <fname> | <lname> | <company> | <addr1> | <addr2> | <city> | <state> | 
       <zip> | <country> |

       And I enter additional informations
       | AdditionalInformation | HomePhone | MobilePhone | AlternateAddress |
       | <remarks> | <homephone> | <mobile> | <addr3> |

       When I click on Register button
       Then I redirected to order summary page

      Examples:
     | customerEmail | <title> | <cFname> | <cLname> | <email> | <pwd> | <dob> | 
    <fname> | <lname> | <company> | <addr1> | <addr2> | <city> | <state> | <zip> 
    | <country> | <remarks> | <homephone> | <mobile> | <addr3> |
   | abc@gmail.com | f | g | f | t | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | h | d | e | e | 
   r | b | w | u |
```

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: Framework : Cucumber with TestNG Language : Java

Comment: Why are you using a scenariooutline? It seems like the data is for a single user? Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. IN the example above I have given only one set of data. But actually the requirement was for multiple users. That's why I used Scenario Outline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be more suitable to be a scenario rather than a scenariooutline. Shortened version of the scenario than you have used. The headers in the exaples table have '<>' which are not necessary.

---

Feature file

```
    Scenario Outline: Test successful registration of a new user
       Then I enter email address of new user as "<customerEmail>"
       Then I enter my personal informations
         | title | customerFirstName | customerLastName |
         | <title> | <cFname> | <cLname> |
       And I enter my address informations
         | firstName | lastName | company |
         | <fname> | <lname> | <company> |

     Examples:
        | customerEmail | title | cFname | cLname | fname | lname | company |
        | abc@gmail.com | f | g | f | e | r | b |
```

---

StepDefinition -

```
public class FormSteps {

    private User user = new User();

    @Then("^I enter email address of new user as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void iEnterEmailAddressOfNewUserAs(String email) {
        //Input details to webpage and store for later use
        user.setEmail(email);
    }

    @Then("^I enter my personal informations$")
    public void iEnterMyPersonalInformations(List<User.UserPersonal> userPers) {
        //Input details to webpage and store for later use
        user.setPersonalDetails(userPers.get(0));
        System.out.println(user);
    }

    @Then("^I enter my address informations$")
    public void iEnterMyAddressInformations(List<User.UserAddress> userAddr) {
        //Input details to webpage and store for later use
        user.setAddressDetails(userAddr.get(0));
        System.out.println(user);
    }
}
```

---

User classes with inner classes - Add a new inner class for the additional info. add other variables.

```
public class User {

    private UserPersonal personal = new UserPersonal();
    private UserAddress address = new UserAddress();

    private String email;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public UserPersonal getPersonalDetails() {
        return personal;
    }
    public void setPersonalDetails(User.UserPersonal personal) {
        this.personal = personal;
    }
    public UserAddress getAddressDetails() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddressDetails(UserAddress address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [personal=" + personal + ", address=" + address
                + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

    public class UserPersonal {
        private String title;
        private String customerFirstName;
        private String customerLastName;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
        public String getCustomerFirstName() {
            return customerFirstName;
        }
        public void setCustomerFirstName(String customerFirstName) {
            this.customerFirstName = customerFirstName;
        }
        public String getCustomerLastName() {
            return customerLastName;
        }
        public void setCustomerLastName(String customerLastName) {
            this.customerLastName = customerLastName;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "UserPersonal [title=" + title + ", customerFirstName="
                    + customerFirstName + ", customerLastName="
                    + customerLastName + "]";
        }               
    }

    public class UserAddress {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String company;
        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }
        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
        public String getCompany() {
            return company;
        }
        public void setCompany(String company) {
            this.company = company;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "UserAddress [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName="
                    + lastName + ", company=" + company + "]";
        }   
    }
}
```

---

This can be easily switched to a scenario. Everything like stepdefinition etc remain the same.

```
Scenario: Test successful registration of a new user
       Then I enter email address of new user as "abc@gmail.com"
       Then I enter my personal informations
         | title | customerFirstName | customerLastName |
         | f | g | f |
       And I enter my address informations
         | firstName | lastName | company |
         | e | r | b |
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your collection of data a name. Lets say its a tax form. Instead of letting your features define HOW that form is filled in just talk about WHEN the form is filled in and let the code below deal with the details

So you would end up with a step

```
When I fill in my tax form
```

and implement it as

```
When "I fill in my tax form" do
  fill_in_tax_form
end
```

and now create a helper method to fill in your tax from

```
module TaxFormStepHelper
  def fill_in_form
  end
end
```

Now because you are actually filling in the form with a programming language you can do all sorts of cool things to make this much much simpler For example one of my steps that fills in a wizard uses the following method

```
  def fill_in_electric_meter_details
    fill_in_common_meter_details
    # 'debt_clearance_meter_serial_number' is  prepopulated from property
    fill_in 'debt_clearance_screen_a', with: 'a'
    fill_in 'debt_clearance_screen_b', with: 'b'
    fill_in 'debt_clearance_screen_f', with: 'f'
    fill_in 'debt_clearance_screen_g', with: 'g'
  end
```

By pushing the implementation of how you fill in the form into lower level test code you make you cukes much much simpler, and at the same time they become much more powerful.

If you want to deal with sad paths you can do things like

```
When I fill in my tax form 
And my employment status is not correct 
Then ...
```

The `When` fills in the form as normal
The `And` overwrite the employment status so its not correct

There is absolutely no need to ever use large tables of examples when cuking. All you achieve by doing this is making your features much harder to read, and your step definitions very much harder to write.

Hope thats of use to you :)

Comment: Hey @diabolist thanks for your reply.. I understood the approach you trying to convey.. But I still doubt if I do not se data tables in feature file (I dont want to use external file as well like excel , csv) then how will I pass data to my helper module?

Comment: I've been cuking for 10 years and haven't used a datatable for at least the last 5 of those. One of the things you haven't understood, yet, is that you never need to pass data into helper modules. Helper modules can get any data they want, all they need to be told is the name of that data, then they can go an ask for it. All your features and scenarios need to do is give the set of data a unique name which makes sense in your particular context.